# R: extract an element after a symbol "="

Tags: r

i have an example like this :

```
M01287=Neuro D
```

and I want to extract only one element after "=" which is the word`'Neuro'` in this case

i tried this command below, but it gives me the whole sentence after "=":

> `sub('.*=', '', x)` -> Neuro D

Do you have a suggestion! thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a second condition to remove everything after space :

```
gsub('.*=| .*', '', 'M01287=Neuro D')
```